# how to make a char field behave like URLField in django

Tags: django

I am using Django and I want a field for URLs I know there is a URLField in Django but I want  that field to be a charfield and I don't want users to submit anything other than URL in that charfield

take a look at my models.py:

```
 class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    social_github = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_twitter = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_website = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

***Please answer how can I make a char field behave like a URL field***

Comment: What is the problem with an `URLField`. In essence it is a `CharField` with some validators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `URLField` is in essence just a `CharField` with some validation (and a default name that defaults to (a translation of) URL and a maximum length of 200. Indeed if we look at the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2310-L2330), we see:

> ```
> class URLField(CharField):
>     default_validators = [validators.URLValidator()]
>     description = _("URL")
>
>     def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, **kwargs):
>         kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 200)
>         super().__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
>
>     def deconstruct(self):
>         name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
>         if kwargs.get("max_length") == 200:
>             del kwargs['max_length']
>         return name, path, args, kwargs
>
>     def formfield(self, **kwargs):
>         # As with CharField, this will cause URL validation to be performed
>         # twice.
>         return super().formfield(**{
>             'form_class': forms.URLField,
>             **kwargs,
>         })
> ```

It also uses a different form field: the `URLField` is [implemented [GitHub] as):

> ```
> class URLField(CharField):
>     widget = URLInput
>     # …
> ```

It will thus use a `URLInput` widget, but there is nothing that prevents you from using another widget. Indeed, we can implement the model with:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # …
    social_github = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    social_twitter = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    social_linkedin = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    social_youtube = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    social_website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    # …
```

If you want to change the widget, for example in a `ModelForm`, you can work with:

```
class MyProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # …
    class Meta:
        # …
        widgets = {
            'social_github': forms.TextInput,
            'social_twitter': forms.TextInput,
            'social_linkedin': forms.TextInput,
            'social_youtube': forms.TextInput,
            'social_website': forms.TextInput
        }
```